# Trigger an event when user scrolls down for x seconds

Tags: javascript, scroll

I need to trigger an event, once, after the user scrolls down for 1 second.
I used the following code, but it triggers the event numerous times, otherwise I think that it sorts of corresponds to what I need?

Thanks !

```
var firstScroll = false;
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    if (!firstScroll){
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("x");
            firstScroll = true;  
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean they must scroll for a second, or after they scroll wait a second and then execute some code?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to be what I wanted! Now, what if I want to trigger that event to SCROLL for 1 second, OR moving the mouse for 1 sec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your scroll check outside of the setTimeout.

```js
var firstScroll = false;
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    if (!firstScroll){
        firstScroll = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("x");
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```